# How to cast an object to type passed to a function?

Tags: c#, object, types, casting

This doesn't compile, but what I'm trying to do is simply casting object to 't' which is passed to the function?

```
public void My_Func(Object input, Type t)
{
   (t)object ab = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t).ConvertFromString(input.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to cast the input object to the given Type t? What shall happen if input is not of type t?

Comment: @FrankE - The function will work in a way that who ever uses it will know to enter the correct type in the function, I take it on my responsibility!

Comment: What do you want to do with the object? Maybe you want to use a generic function `public void My_Func<T>(T input)` ?

Comment: There is already a [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) method doing this. Try read about it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
object ab = Convert.Changetype(input, t);
```

however, it looks like you want to use `ab` in a strongly-typed manner, which you can only do so by using generics:

```
public void My_Func<T>(Object input)
{
   T ab = (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: What´s the difference between `object ab = Convert.Changetype(input, t);` and `object ab = input`?

Comment: @ekholm `object ab = "01/01/2008"` vs. `object ab = Convert.ChangeType("01/01/2008", typeof(DateTime))`

Comment: This still doesn't compile - it should have been: T ab = (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T)); but Thank you! you did it.

Comment: When I debug I see in the watch window when running code `object ab = Convert.Changetype(input, t);` the watch window shows `Type: object {short}`. But when running the code  `T ab = (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T))`; and evaluating ab I get `Type: short`. Nevertheless when running `GetType()` on both of them I get the exact same result `(System.Int16)`, can you please explain this phenomenon?

Comment: @BornToCode thanks, fixed it. The watch window is probably showing you the type of the variable (`object`), as well as the eventual runtime type of it's value (`short`). In this case, the `short` value is "boxed" in order to be referenced as an `object`. In the second case, the variable itself is a `short`. In either case, `GetType` will give you the actual type of the value itself, which is `Int16` (same as short).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void My_Func(Object input, Type t)
{
    object test = new object();
    test = Convert.ChangeType(test, t);
    test = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t).ConvertFromString(input.ToString());
}
```